# Vaadin: How do make a button align to the top right of my page?

Tags: vaadin

I need to align a button to the right of my page in a vertical layout. 
Please tell me method to do this.

```
private Button createBackButton() {
    Button bButton = new Button("Back");
    bButton.setIcon(FontAwesome.ARROW_LEFT);
    bButton.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            doSomething();
        }
    });
    return bButton;
}
```

Comment: VerticalLayout has method setComponentAlignment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Null,

In order to align your button to the top-right of your VerticalLayout, use VerticalLayout's setComponentAlignment() method. Also note that the VerticalLayout itself needs to be big enough so that the button can even have some space to move around in there so it looks like it's being aligned to the top-right. By default the VerticalLayout will just get as big as the components inside it. You need to give it a bigger size using setWidth() and setHeight(), or make it take up the whole space as its parent component/layout using setSizeFull() (note that the parent layout, if any, also needs to be big enough so it has space inside it too).

So the code would look like:

```
VerticalLayout vl = new VerticalLayout();
vl.setSizeFull();
Button backButton = createBackButton();
vl.addComponent(backButton);
vl.setComponentAlignment(backButton,Alignment.TOP_RIGHT);
```

Hope that helps.